# A pair of sets disconnecting the complement of a set with empty interior

Tags: general-topology

Let $E \subset \mathbb{R}^n$, with $\operatorname{int}(E) = \emptyset$  ($\operatorname{int}(E)$ is the interior of $E$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$).

Suppose that $E^c$ is disconnected.

Let $U,V \subset \mathbb{R}^n$, with $U\cap V = \emptyset$, $U \neq \emptyset$, $V \neq \emptyset$, $\overline{U} \cap V = \emptyset$, $\overline{V} \cap U= \emptyset, E^c = U \cup V$, where $U,V$ open relative to $E^c$. Show that ${\overline{U} }^c \cap {\overline{V} }^c  = \emptyset$.

($\overline{U} $ and $\overline{V}$ is the closure in $\mathbb{R}^n$.)

#### My ideas:

Suppose that  ${\overline{U} }^c \cap {\overline{V} }^c  \neq \emptyset$. Let $x \in {\overline{U} }^c \cap {\overline{V} }^c $, then $x \notin  U$ and $x \notin V$.

Note that $E  = U^c \cap V^c$, then $x \in E$.

I stopped here. I am trying to show that $ U^c \cap V^c$ is open in $E$.

If I prove this problem, I understand a theorem that I am studying. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that we have $A^c \cap B^c = (A \cup B)^c$ for all $A,\, B$ (de Morgan), and $\overline{A} \cup \overline{B} = \overline{A\cup B}$ as well as $\overline{A}^c = \operatorname{int}(A^c)$. Hence

$$\begin{align}
\overline{U}^c \cap \overline{V}^c &= \varnothing\\
\iff (\overline{U} \cup \overline{V})^c &= \varnothing\\
\iff (\overline{U \cup V})^c &= \varnothing\\
\iff (\overline{E^c})^c &= \varnothing\\
\iff \operatorname{int}(E^{cc}) &= \varnothing\\
\iff \operatorname{int}(E) &= \varnothing.
\end{align}$$

Comment: please can you explain with more details why ${\overline{E^c}}^c = \emptyset \ <=> \  int(E)^{cc} = \emptyset$ ?

Comment: Typo, misplaced parenthesis (although of course the result is the same here).

Comment: I not understand ( my english is terrible, sorry ). The right is ${\overline{E^c}}^c = \emptyset <=> {int(\overline{E^c})}^c$ ?

Comment: No, we have $(\overline{E^c})^c = \operatorname{int}(E^{cc})$ from the general $(\overline{A})^c = \operatorname{int}(A^c)$. "The complement of the closure is the interior of the complement". The complement of the closure is the set of points that have a neighbourhood that doesn't meet $A$. A neighbourhood not meeting $A$ is a neighbourhood that is contained in $A^c$, and a point having a neighbourhood contained in $A^c$ is an interior point of $A^c$. (Actually, it was also correct the way I had it written first, because $\overline{B^c} = (\operatorname{int}(B))^c$, but since I hadn't listed

Comment: that one, it was not proper to move from $(\overline{E^c})^c$ to $(\operatorname{int}(E))^{cc}$.)